# Python imaplib: Authentication failed for yahoo account irrespective of correct credentials

Tags: authentication, yahoo, imaplib

I'm using python's imaplib for fetching and manipulating mails. Everything works fine with gmail account. But, when I try to login to yahoo account using the same, authenctication failed with following error, irrespective of correct credentials provided:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/imaplib.py", line 593, in login
    raise self.error(dat[-1])
imaplib.error: b'[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] LOGIN Invalid credentials'
```

```
yahooSmtpServer = "imap.mail.yahoo.com"
yahooSmtpPort = 993
client = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(yahooSmtpServer, yahooSmtpPort)
client.login(username, password)
```

Comment: I need to modify setting for allowing insecured app to access the mail in yahoo mail settings.

Comment: You should generate an app specific password instead.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**: Generate App Password by following instructions [from this link](https://en-global.help.yahoo.com/kb/generate-password-sln15241.html)

Long answer:

From [Download your email from Yahoo Mail with IMAP](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN15241.html)

**Your login info**

If you're using Yahoo Account Key or some older email apps, [generate an app password](https://en-global.help.yahoo.com/kb/generate-password-sln15241.html) and use that for your account password.

- Email address - Your full email address (name@domain.com)
- Password - Your account's password
- Requires authentication - Yes